# How to nest an existing dictionary dynamically in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a program that can ask user to categorize and existing dictionary:
here is my dictionary:

```
>>> print Vocab_World
{'excelent': 'awesome', 'quit': 'exit', 'great': 'good', 'ceken': 
'bilir', 'tremendous': 'fabolous', 'gurbet': 'hasret', 'postpone': 
'put_offt', 'ozlem': 'hasret'}
```

Now I want to ask the user if they want to categorize the same meaning words as nested dictionary and I want to have a list like below one for the categorized words

```
{'Adverb' : {'excelent': 'awesome','great': 'good','tremendous': 'fabolous'} }
```

.

```
categorized_words = raw_input("Please select the words that you want to categorize")
new_category = raw_input("Please input the new category name ")
categorized_World=Vocab_World[new_category][0][categorized_words]
```

Is there a way of doing that dynamically based on user input ?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried so far and where did you get stuck?

Comment: but the issue is since there are more than 1 categorized words how i can iterate it dynamically ? Category is 1 but the wrods are could be more

Comment: Don't post your code as a comment, edit your question and include all the relevant information.

Comment: Is categorized_words a list of keys from Vocab_World?

Comment: No, that will be a new key which will get from new_category raw_input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Vocab_World = {'excelent': 'awesome', 'quit': 'exit', 'great': 'good', 'ceken': 
'bilir', 'tremendous': 'fabolous', 'gurbet': 'hasret', 'postpone': 
'put_offt', 'ozlem': 'hasret'}

Categorized_World = {}  # output dict
chosen_words = []       # array to store all the chosen words

while True:
    categorized_words = raw_input("Words to categorize separated by ',' or Q/q for quit)")
    if categorized_words.lower() == 'q':
        break
    chosen_words.extend(categorized_words.split(','))
    new_category = raw_input("Please input the new category name ")
    Categorized_World[new_category] = {i:Vocab_World[i] for i in
                                       categorized_words.split(',') if i in Vocab_World}

# Add words that are not catgorized
Categorized_World.update({i:Vocab_World[i] for i in Vocab_World if i not in chosen_words})

print(Categorized_World)
```

Running this and inputing:

```
excelent,great,tremendous
adverb
q
```

Would return:

```
{'adverb': {'excelent': 'awesome', 'great': 'good', 'tremendous': 'fabolous'}, 
'quit': 'exit', 'ceken': 'bilir', 'gurbet': 'hasret', 
'postpone': 'put_offt', 'ozlem': 'hasret'}
```

Comment: awesome, that worked. what exactly {i:Vocab_World[i]} means  can you elaborate a little bit please? also is there any way to include the uncategorized key,values to the new Categorized_World dict ? like {'adverb': {'excelent': 'awesome', 'great': 'good', 'tremendous': 'fabolous'},'ceken':'bilir','gurbet' : 'hasret' } ?

Comment: @NANIS yes, well everything is possible I guess. It's just a few lines of code. About your other question. (i:Vocab_Wordl[i]... That is a dict comprehension. Try googling it!

Comment: that is awesome and it worked. Now, i am working to understand the code. Thanks so much again.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Vocab_World= {'excelent': 'awesome', 'quit': 'exit', 'great': 'good', 'ceken': 
              'bilir', 'tremendous': 'fabolous', 'gurbet': 'hasret', 'postpone': 
              'put_offt', 'ozlem': 'hasret'}

categorized_words = raw_input("Please select the words that you want to categorize ")
new_category = raw_input("Please input the new category name ")

Categorized_World=dict()
tmp=dict()
for w in categorized_words.split():
  tmp.update({w:Vocab_World[w]})

Categorized_World.update({new_category:tmp})
print Categorized_World
```

Output is:

```
Please select the words that you want to categorize excelent great tremendous
Please input the new category name Adverb
{'Adverb': {'excelent': 'awesome', 'tremendous': 'fabolous', 'great': 'good'}}
```